# Regex replace between digits

Tags: regex

I have the following timecode I want to do a replace on:

```
00 04 02 01 -- > 00:04:02:01
```

How would I replace the space between the two digits with a colon? I have come up with `\d\s\d`, but that obviously includes the digits as well.

Comment: What toolset or programming language? This may only need to be a simple string replacement, rather than a regex.

Comment: No language, I'm in TextMate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture your digits, then use them when replacing:

```
(\d)\s(?=\d)
```

replace with:

```
$1:
```

---

The following example uses JavaScript:

```
var str = '00 04 02 01';
str = str.replace(/(\d)\s(?=\d)/g, '$1:');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7arUa/

Comment: Is there no way to replace a space between two digits?